# Selecting one of the duplicate rows based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to filter the duplicate rows out based on one column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    b.name,
    b.number
FROM
    b
LEFT JOIN a
    ON a.name = b.name
ORDER BY
    b.name
ASC;
```

And the result is:

```
id,name,number
1  Bob  NULL
1  Bob  100
2  Bob  NULL
2  Bob  200
3  Bob  NULL
3  Bob  300
4  Bob  400
```

I'm trying to achieve the result like this:

```
id,name,number
1  Bob  100
2  Bob  200
3  Bob  300
4  Bob  400
```

Comment: where [number] is not null

Comment: Are you trying to filter out `null` values or do you want to perform an aggregate on the `number` field?  What if 2 non-null numbers are returned?

Comment: If there's two rows with the same id, and one has the number, I'd like to pick that row. However, if there's two rows with NULL number, just pick null. There's also other non-duplicate rows with value of NULL, so I'd like them to keep thatw ay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to selectively filter out `NULL` values in `b.number` field:

```
SELECT id, name, number
FROM (
  SELECT a.id, b.name, b.number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(b.number, -1) DESC) AS rn 
  FROM b
  LEFT JOIN a ON a.name = b.name) AS t
  WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY name ASC
```

The above query handles only cases with one, or at most two rows per `id`, with one of them, or both, being `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the `NULL` values, I would suggest aggregation:

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, SUM(b.number) as number
FROM b LEFT JOIN
     a
     ON a.name = b.name
GROUP BY a.id, b.name;
```

Alternatively, just use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, b.number
FROM b LEFT JOIN
     a
     ON a.name = b.name
WHERE b.name IS NOT NULL;
```